# Where do i change HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe on apache ?

Tags: php, apache, http, subdomain

I recently upgrade my apache server and i notice it forbidden underscore in the domain.

I saw there is work around to enable HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe 
instead of HttpProtocolOptions strickt

But where do i write this command ? 
I try to write it on the httpd.conf but it dosen't helped.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it into your server configuration (httpd.conf or apache2.conf) or into your VirtualHosts. These are the possible [contexts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) for this setting. This is what the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#httpprotocoloptions) says.

Hope I could help you.